# Rollback DB with real data when using pytest-django, pytest-splinter and pytest-bdd

Tags: python, django, pytest, rollback, pytest-django

For BDD of our Django project, we combine pytest-splinter with py-test django (and pytest-bdd).

We run our test on real data. Therefore, we would like all changes made to the DB rolled back after each test, or alternatively after all tests.

Our question:
What's the correct way to

- use a real DB
- have proper rollback after browser testing ?

Where we are thus far:
We overwrite the py.test `django_db_setup` fixture as follows in `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup(
    request,
    django_test_environment,
    django_db_blocker,
    django_db_use_migrations,
    django_db_keepdb,
    django_db_modify_db_settings,
):
    return
```

When **not** using the py.test `live_server` fixture, DB changes made via the browser are not rolled back, and accumulate in our DB.

```
@scenario('user_management.feature', 'Add a new user')
def test_add_a_new_user(db):
    pass
```

When using the py.test `live_server` fixture we get an error that the DB tables cannot be flushed (which is not the behavior we would like).

```
@scenario('user_management.feature', 'Add a new user')
def test_add_a_new_user(db, live_server):
    pass
```

This is the error:

`django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint`

`django.core.management.base.CommandError: Database carbon-delta-lab couldn't be flushed.`

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: And just marking the tests with the `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)` is not sufficient in your case?

Comment: Normally, if I need to test with a real data, I dump the db once and store the dump as a django fixture file; on test run start, the fixture is loaded into an empty db via `loaddata` call in `django_db_setup` and the db is destroyed after the test run. Handling fixture files is usually easier as these are JSON text files.